# Python: printing from txt file to list

Tags: python

I would like to convert this text file to a list. But I'm having some error. Please enlighten me on why I have an error.

```
goods= {}
    with open("goods.txt") as f:
        for key, val in f:
            key[0] = inv[1], int(inv[2])
    print(goods)
```

**goods.txt**:
a1 marker 5 
a2 pen 5 
a3 eraser 4 
a4 pencil  10

**Prints out List**:

```
goods = {'A':['marker', 5], 'B':['pens',5] … }
```

Comment: You are not using `goods` anywhere in the code

Comment: also, it seems you want a `dict`, not a `list`?

Comment: yes, dict list.

Comment: Add the error as well in post. Explain each line in the code (print each key in the dict for example ) which will help you to debug and understand how to debug. This is a debugging problem. Just to start with can you explain what are you trying to do here `for key, val in f`?

Comment: Please provide the entire error message, as well as a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
goods= {}
with open("goods.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        itemId,itemName,qty = line.split()
        goods[itemId] = [itemName,int(qty)]
print(goods)
```

This will output:

> {'a1': ['marker', 5], 'a2': ['pen', 5], 'a3': ['eraser', 4],
>   'a4': ['pencil', 10]}

Comment: Output is confusing. If you are converting into ints then I do not expect list to contain integers as Strings. You don;t need extra bracets for unpacking. `itemId,itemName,qty= line.split()` is enough

Comment: @mad_ Great catch! I edited the int after i re-read the question thus forgot to change the output. Thanks for informing!

Answer (score 0):

- I don't think that this is the result you are getting. The actual result is an error. You can not just interpret an opened text-file as dictionary.
- `goods = {}` is never used.
- you try to assign a value to key[0], which is a local loop-variable `key[0] = inv[1], int(inv[2])`

E.g. have a look at this code, maybe it helps you understand this a little better...

```
with open("goods.txt", mode='r') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line.split(' '))
```